# Why 0 is printing as most significant digit in c++

Tags: c++, c++11

In the following program, I have attached code and its sample output I don't know why it is printing 0 as the most significant digit.
I have tried different test cases but it just adds 0 to most significant digit.
Is it a bug or I'm missing some concept.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int kthLargest (vector<int> arr, int n, int k){
  map<int,int> a;
  cout<<a.size();
  vector<int>::iterator i;
  for(i=arr.begin();i!=arr.end();i++)
  {
    a[*i]=a[*i]+1;
  }
  map<int,int>::iterator j;
  int sum=0;
  for(j=a.begin();j!=a.end();j++)
  {
    sum+=j->second;
    if(sum>(n-k))
    {
      sum=j->first;
      break;
    }
  }
  return sum;
}
int main()
{
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(NULL);
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    vector<int> a(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        cin>>a[i];
    }
    int k;
    cin>>k;
    cout<<kthLargest(a,n,k);
    return 0;
}
```

**input**

```
5
1 2 3 4 5
3
```

**output**

```
04
```

[image]

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. What _test cases_? What is the specific problem you are facing?

Comment: Please [learn how to format your posts properly](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: And please read [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Comment: And you should probably also [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [this Stack Overflow question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/), and all of http://idownvotedbecau.se/ to learn some reasons you get negative votes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are outputting 2 numbers, one immediately after the other:

```
cout<<a.size();
```

and

```
cout<<kthLargest(a,n,k);
```

The first is 0 (the map is empty), the second is the final result of your function call. The formatting is behaving as expected, and no leading 0 is being output anywhere.

You probably forgot about the `cout<<a.size();`, so just remove it and your code will be fine.